# How can I use margin-top for <li> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
li{
 padding: 5px 4px 6px 7px;
   margin-top: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
 list-style: none;
}
li + li {
 border-top: 1px solid #eff0f1;
}
li:hover{
 background-color: #f7f8f8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something else</li>
  <li>something else again</li>
</ul>
```

As you see, there isn't any white space in the top of those rows. In other word, `margin-top: 3px;` doesn't work. Why? And how can I fix it?

---

**Current output:**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: That's the defoult. try 10px

Comment: Downvoter what's wrong with my question?

Comment: Collapsing margins ~ https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/

Comment: @Phil I took a look at the link you provided .. but still the problem is there..!

Comment: Just reading the article isn't going to magically fix it. What did you change?

Comment: border is adjacent to the background, that's the standard box-model. You'll need to change how you handle the border.

Comment: that white space at the bottom of the 2nd list item isn't from the margin-bottom of the 2nd list item, it's from the margin-top of the 3rd list item

Answer (score 2):

The margin is the space outside of the border and padding is the space in between the content and the border. Refer to the [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) for more details. You can wrap div around your list item content and assign the margin and padding to it but keep the borders on the list item.

```css
.content {
  padding: 5px 4px 6px 7px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  display: block;
}
li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #eff0f1;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.content:hover {
  background-color: #f7f8f8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="content">something</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">something else</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">something else again</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```