# How can I set margin top/bottom to a li?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
li {
  padding: 5px 4px 6px 7px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  list-style: none;
}
li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #eff0f1;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #f7f8f8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something else</li>
  <li>something else again</li>
</ul>
```

As you see, there isn't any white space in the top of those rows. In other word, `margin-top: 3px;` doesn't work. Why? And how can I fix it?

---

**Current output:**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

---

**Note:** I can wrap everything which is into `<li>` to a `<div>`. And then set all those `li`'s properties to that `<div>`. But I want to know how can I do that with my current HTML structure?

Comment: You need to set the `padding`, not the margins. Margins adjust the outside spacing between elements, while the padding adjusts the spacing inside of the elements.

Comment: @EvanBechtol What? As you see I've set `padding` already `padding: 5px 4px 6px 7px;`. But nothing changes.

Comment: Also have a read about [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing), it will explain why one of your margins is dissapearing

Comment: You can't get the effect you're looking for with your current HTML structure. The `background` fills the area between the borders. Thus, you can't get a gap between the `background` and the `border` without another element.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Well why I can get a white space for the bottom of `li`, But I cannot for the top of it?

Comment: Because you've got `border-top` set. The white space below is the combination of the bottom margin of current  `li` and the top margin of the sibling `li`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ah I see

Comment: @MartinAJ, when you don't get answers to a question ***it is absolutely inappropriate to ask the same question again***.

Comment: @zzzzBov This question isn't the same as my previous question .. This one tries to keep the current HTML structure.

Comment: @MartinAJ, all you added was a short "note" at the end, which should have been added to your previous question as an edit. It absolutely is [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39029391/497418), and looking at your question history, this isn't the first time you've done this. [This sort of behavior should not be tolerated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262929/prevent-punish-self-duplicates).

Comment: @zzzzBov Ah ok .. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is due to collapsing margins - from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing:

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

To get around this, I would wrap the content of the li in a span or div and put your original `li` padding on that, and then put the 3px margin as padding on your `li` instead:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 3px 0; /* this is in place of your margin */
}
li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #eff0f1;
}
li > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 4px 6px 7px; /* this is you original li padding */
}
li:hover > span {
  background-color: #f7f8f8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>something</span></li>
  <li><span>something else</span></li>
  <li><span>something else again</span></li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

If you cannot change your html then you will need something like this:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 4px 6px 7px;
  margin-bottom:7px; /* 3px margin plus 1px for the border */
  position:relative;
}
li + li:before {        /* this is a pseudo element to create the border */
  content:'';
  display:block; 
  height:1px;
  background: #eff0f1;
  position:absolute;
  top:-4px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #f7f8f8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something else</li>
  <li>something else again</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well actually I didn't want to change the HTML structure .. but thank you anyway. upvote for your effort.

Comment: Look, I cannot implement your first approach on my [real codes](https://jsfiddle.net/nfv149et/). Actually I want to use `<a>` instead of `<span>` in your first approach. May you please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using relatively-positioned pseudo-elements:

```css
li {
  padding: 5px 4px 6px 7px;
  list-style: none;
}
li + li {
  margin-top: 6px; /* total distance between elements */
}
li + li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -8px; /* padding-top (5px) + margin-top (3px) */
  border-top: 1px solid #eff0f1;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #f7f8f8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something else</li>
  <li>something else again</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this approach work on old browsers like IE8 or even IE7 ?

Comment: It works on IE8, but I don't think so for IE7. [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore). Though I've never actually met anyone who uses something older than IE8 still. Caniuse.com doesn't even keep compatibility statistics for it.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/huh7d6z4/) you can try to ad another elements inside `li` ..
Your margin it's working but you can't see because when you margin an element even the border is margin-en with the element. To prove that you can raise the `margin-top:20px;` and you can see that the margin is working. The `padding` is used to create space from inside the element.

```
+----------------------------+
|                            |
|          margin            |
|                            |
|   *******border**********  |
|   *                     *  |
|   *      padding        *  |
|   *                     *  |
|   *   ---------------   *  |
|   *   ---------------   *  |
|   *   ---ELEMENT-----   *  |
|   *   ---------------   *  |
|   *   ---------------   *  |
|   *                     *  |
|   ***********************  |
|                            |
|                            |
+----------------------------+
```

Comment: check the jsfiddle and tell me if this is what are you looking for ? just as an example because you can make that span as a div

Comment: @edisoni.1337 I didn't downvote, but I do wonder how this answers the question. It's about the background-color and the border, the padding was alright already?

Comment: He just wanted to get the result and i made in another way. For everything are many ways so i did it in my way. It's not a wrong answer it's an anser that work across all browsers

Comment: @Randy so you see ? the chosen correct answer is copy of my code + @ 4castle code

Comment: @edisoni.1337 yes I see, I didn't open the JSFiddle before. Usually I only check code snippets, I don't like external links. Maybe its a bad habbit :P

Comment: This is unfair it's second time for today that someone just copy-paste my code and get the answer as correct :P i really hate code snippets because it's hard to work with and make changes

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**

The result is very easy to achieve. Simply add

```
    background-clip: content-box;
```

to your CSS.

```css
li {
  padding: 5px 4px 6px 7px;
  list-style: none;
  
    background-clip: content-box;
}
li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #eff0f1;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #f7f8f8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>padding</li>
  <li>padding else</li>
  <li>padding else again</li>
</ul>
```

**full exmample of background-clip:**

```css
div {
  background-color:#faa;
  border:3px dotted black;
  margin:20px;
  padding:20px;
}

.normal {
    background-clip: border-box;
}

.padding-box {
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

.content-box {
  /* note this does not color the background of the border */
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">
  Normal
</div>

<div class="content-box">
  content box
</div>

<div class="padding-box">
  padding box
</div>
```

Comment: Well I don't see any white space between the border and however's background.

Comment: @MartinAJ Updated.

Comment: Oh .. `background-clip` seems a great property for doing what I'm looking for. upote

Comment: @edisoni.1337 Correct .. Actually that's a huge problem for me, because the most of my website's users use old browsers like IE8.